# PHP session_start without setting Set-Cookie header in response

Tags: php, http, cookies, http-headers, session-cookies

Quite simply, I want to call PHP's `session_start()` without returning the `Set-Cookie` response header to the browser.  It appears that calling session_start() implicitly sends the `Set-Cookie` header.

Is there any way to do this?  I have tried adding an additional Set-Cookie header with an expired cookie in the session_start, and other ways, but nothing has worked and I can't find docs on this.

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION**: The reason for this is that I want to (have an AJAX call) return data (on the same domain) but *not* set a session cookie when returned. (Accepted answer works as desired)

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After call the session_start(), you could use:

```
header_remove ( "Set-Cookie");
```

This will remove the cookie created at session_start() call.

Comment: Thank you, this was the correct answer to my question.  This has the desired effect; the request may send the cookie, which can get session information, but the set-cookie will not be sent on the *return*